# Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 4096 (request: 4214)

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

I have MariaDB + Nginx on Linux Debian 9(stretch).
After installing MariaDB it and trying to start it, I got the error saying: 
`[Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 4096 (request: 4214)`. 
So I googled it and it told me that I should change `LimiNOFILE` to 10000 in `/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service`. I did that, did deamon-reload and it did absolutely nothing. I am still getting the same error message. I tried reinstalling MariaDB but that didn't help either. I also added `LimitMEMLOCK=10000` at the very end of my file, that didn't change anything.

Full traceback:

[Link](https://hastebin.com/asijeyogat.sql)

Thank you in advance

Comment: there can be more of LimiNOFILE  in your system see https://haydenjames.io/could-not-increase-number-of-max_open_files-to-more-than/

Comment: @nbk yes I already checked that site and only `/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service` showed me something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by reinstalling MariaDB with

> $ sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server

And you should check if it's still on the system with:

> $ sudo dpkg -l | grep mariadb

And if it is, do:

> $ sudo apt-get purge mariadb-common

But before doing that I killed everything that had to do with MariaDB/MySQL via `htop`.
And then the standart procedure with installing it:

> $ sudo apt update
>
> $ sudo apt install mariadb-server
>
> $ sudo mysql_secure_installation

Comment: Great answer! My mysql server would not start. After purging it as described and doing a clean new install it's back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because of the limit set by the SystemD configuration file for the service. If that's the case, you can solve it by editing `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service` and increasing it to the requested value:

```
LimitNOFILE=4214
```

... or wathever value you want:

```
LimitNOFILE=100000
```

*open_files_limit* won't have any effect if the operating system or the init system has a lower limit for the user or service.

Comment: This file doesn't exist for me

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to change it at service level

You must also edit

> /etc/mysql/conf.d/limits.cnf

And have these lines in them

```
[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 10000
```

Then,

> service mysql restart

And you could increase the number  to 1000000  in limits.conf and mysql.service

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The file /etc/mysql/conf.d/limits.cnf is empty...
Should I still add it?

Comment: So it is not the system did you check out my.cnf, if there is a line like in my post?

Comment: These are the only files in the folder 
`/etc/mysql/conf.d/`

And these are:

`mysql.cnf` and `mysqldump.cnf`

`mysql.cnf` had this only line:

[mysql]

So I changed it to:

`[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 10000`

But that did nothing. I still get the error...

Answer (score 0):

Server settings like `openfile_files_limits` have no effect, if the operating system limits the number of open files, and will always result in an error. Since the server by default is running as user mysql, it can't change the system values (and there is also no code in the server which changes these limits).

Default value of open files on a Linux system is by default 1024, and can be determined by

```
$> ulimit -n
1024
```

So in case you have root privileges or you're in the sudo'ers list, just increase this value. `man ulimit` will give you more information.

Comment: Yes I do have root privileges for the server but when I do `man ulimit`, the output is `No manual entry for ulimit`.

Answer (score 0):

Just noting the solution for me was to fix a bad config in the `tmpdir` variable. It was set to `/mysqltmp` (probably because `/tmp` was pretty small). I fixed it with:

```
mkdir -p /mysqltmp
chown mysql.mysql /mysqltmp
```

I am guessing setting `tmpdir` to a dir that doesn't exist or has the wrong permissions triggers this message.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a syntax error in the MySQL config file: `my.cnf`

after removing the error line, I started MySQL service successfully.